# Traducción alternativa para "far from perfect"

Tags: traducción, expresiones, solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

*"Far from perfect"* es una expresión para resaltar imperfecciones en algo sin especificar las mismas, se utiliza frecuentemente en contraste a una mención del trabajo realizado para obtener ese algo.

He visto esta expresión traducida como "dista de ser perfecto" y como "está lejos de ser perfecto", pero estas traducciones me parecen demasiado literales y preferiría una expresión que se adapte mejor al uso en contraste a una mención del esfuerzo realizado.

Comment: Ambas traducciones son efectivas. Inclusive agregaría "dista **mucho** de ser perfecto". No sé por qué buscas una expresión diferente, tal vez una sola palabra, cuando en inglés la perífrasis es indicativa del mismo contraste que transmite la versión en español.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que dices explícitamente que *no* quieres usar la expresión estándar en español (que, como bien apunta Charlie, sería "[distar/estar lejos] de ser perfecto"), aún cuando esta tiene exactamente la misma estructura, significado y uso que la expresión en inglés... Lo más que te puedo ofrecer son sinónimos de "imperfecto", como por ejemplo:

> **[mejorable](http://dle.rae.es/?w=mejorable)**
>
> 1. adj. Que se puede mejorar.

O bien:

> **[perfectible](http://dle.rae.es/?w=perfectible)**
>
> 1. adj. Capaz de perfeccionarse o de ser perfeccionado.

O bien:

> **[incompleto, ta](http://dle.rae.es/?w=incompleto)**
>
> 1. adj. No completo (|| acabado, perfecto).

Ejemplo de uso:

> *His work is quite good. However, it is **far from perfect***.
>
> Su obra está muy bien. No obstante, es **mejorable**.
>   Su trabajo es muy bueno. Sin embargo, es **perfectible**.
>   Su obra está bastante bien. Aún y así, es **incompleta**.

Comment: Your usage example in English stresses the context that far from perfect is said by someone trying not to be too critical. None of the proposed Spanish suggestions seems to have quite that flavour.

Comment: @mdewey I agree with you that the nuance in both languages is different, but  -- leaving "incompleta" aside -- don't you think that "mejorable" and "perfectible" are softer than "far from perfect"? "**far** from perfect"  means that it would take it a lot of time or work to become perfect. To me, "perfectible" and "mejorable" could mean "close to being perfect/fine."

Comment: @Gustavson I was beginning to feel it may be verging on untranslatable. I had upvoted this answer already even if I felt the suggestions were far from perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque la traducción sea literal, es la que mejor suena en español (negritas mías):

> *El caso de una Televisión estatal que vive exclusivamente de la publicidad sólo se produce en Europa en nuestro país. Aunque ello tiene ciertamente algunos inconvenientes y el sistema **dista de ser perfecto**, tiene, sin embargo, indiscutibles ventajas, especialmente la de que el propietario de un receptor no paga ni un céntimo por el servicio: éste es absolutamente gratuito.*
>
> Jesús Aparicio Bernal, "Noticias de televisión", 1966 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Los actores cómicos varones no necesitaron parecerse a Adonis para cumplir los objetivos que se esperaban de ellos. Bob Hope siempre fue un tipo feo, Groucho **distaba de ser perfecto**, Jerry Lewis se autotransformaba en un ser risible, Danny de Vito parece el tapón de una botella y Woody Allen no es ni de lejos un galán.*
>
> Alicia Giménez Bartlett, "La deuda de Eva. Del pecado de ser feas y el deber de ser hermosas", 2002 (España).

Tu otra opción también se usa:

> *Tal cual es, sin embargo, aunque inferior con mucho a la Constitución de 1812, por más que esté **lejos de ser perfecto**, el Estatuto Real no dejó por eso de tener la gloria de romper el largo silencio impuesto a la España por la violencia.*
>
> Antonio Pirala, "Historia de la guerra civil y de los partidos liberal y carlista, I", 1868 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Además, Explorer está **lejos de ser perfecto** por una razón: le falta un lector integrado de correo electrónico y grupo de noticias.*
>
> Excélsior, 06/01/1997 (México).

Para que veas que es una expresión usada en español desde hace más de medio siglo, aunque al parecer antes se usaba "de la perfección" en vez de "de ser perfecto":

> *Mucho más agradable es á Dios el que piensa la gravedad de sus proprios pecados, y la poquedad de sus virtudes, y **cuán lejos está de la perfeción** de los sanctos, que el que disputa cuál es el mayor ó menor sancto.*
>
> Fray Luis de Granada, "Traducción de la Imitación de Cristo de Kempis", 1536 (España).

Answer (score 2):

Además de las excelentes respuestas ya indicadas, me gustaría añadir una expresión que me parece bastante idiomática:

> Ni mucho menos perfecto

Así, tomando un ejemplo ya utilizado:

> Su trabajo es muy bueno. Sin embargo, no es ni mucho menos perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Para traducir esta frase, de veras se necesita el contexto, porque esta frase se puede usar con varios matices en inglés.  Voy a considerar un contexto posible pero quién sabe si es el que tú querías.

Un uso de esta frase podemos ver en la letra de la canción Rise Against - Far From Perfect (Wolves).  Aquí quiere decir

> Reconocemos que no somos perfectos / Reconozco que no soy perfecto

o bien

> Nadie es perfecto.

Es una especie de modismo.  Literalmente la frase significa otra cosa.  Pero tal y como se usa, muchas veces viene siendo "Nadie es perfecto; ni modo; ¿ahora qué?"